# Relation between Normed space and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Below is what i have proved:

1. If $V$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies parallelogram equality, then there exists an inner product $\langle \bullet,\bullet\rangle$ such that $\langle \bullet,\bullet \rangle = \lVert \bullet \rVert^2$
2. If $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lVert \bullet \rVert \triangleq \sqrt{\langle \bullet \rangle}$, then $\lVert \bullet \rVert$ is a norm and $\langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{4}(\lVert x+y\rVert^2 - \lVert x-y\rVert^2)$.

I thought *defining a norm as square root of inner product $\langle x,x\rangle$* is just *one possinle* way to define norm on an inner product space.

However, the below is the article in wikipedia about impossibility of defining $p-norm$ on an inner product space:

"p ≠ 2 is a normed space but not an inner product space, because this norm does not satisfy the parallelogram equality required of a norm to have an inner product associated with it"

I don't think what i proved above give this conclusion in wikipeia.. What should i prove to conclude this?

Plus, it's on wikipedia that $2$-notm is completely natural to define as so, but it's not *that* natural to take square root to inner product to define norm on an inner product space to me. Why do we specifically use 2-norm?

Moreover, what's the point of relating two concepts inner product and norm, literally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just think of the ordinary scalar product in $2$ or $3$ dimension. This is where these concepts  (inner product, norm) originally started out..

If we have an inner product on a space, then geometrically it's more or less nothing else but the ability to talk about *angles* and *lengths* (length=norm). By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\langle x,y\rangle^2\le \langle x,x\rangle\cdot \langle y,y\rangle\,$$
that is, $\left|\displaystyle\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\cdot\|y\|} \right|\le 1$,
supposed that we define the norm as the 2d and 3d cases geometrically motivates (by the Pythagorean theorem). So there is an angle $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta=\left|\displaystyle\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\cdot\|y\|} \right|$.
And, most importantly, we have the notion of *orthogonality* (which happens to coincide with the case $\theta=90^\circ$).

If we have only a norm $\|\_\|$ on a real vector space, as you stated you proved, the sufficient and necessary condition to the existence of an inner product $\langle -,-\rangle$ such that $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle$, is that the norm satisfies the *parallelogram law*.

As wikipedia says, this is not the case for the $p$-norms $p\ne 2$.

Comment: What's the reason for defining $\lVert - \rVert$ as $\sqrt{\langle -,-\rangle}$, not another function $f(\langle -,- \rangle)$? I'm confused of the meaning of "a norm *induced by* inner product"..

Comment: Well, how to say, this is a good question. The primarily answer is the pure analogy to 2d-3d geometry, applying the Pythagorean theorem. However, it could perhaps make sense to consider any other function of the (quadratic form of the) inner product, that will make a norm. I don't state, only $f=\sqrt{\cdot}$ can do it, good question.